# How can I modify my this badge on my site?

Tags: html, facebook, sidebar

How can i delete the text "Jeffrey Dowell Photography" and "Promote Your Page Too"  and relevent link info above and below this facebook badge. I just want the facebook badge to show, and nothing above and below. And then scale it up to larger. I tried deleting some stuff, and it just makes it disappear on my page.
http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/

```
<!-- Facebook Badge START --><a href="https://www.facebook.com/JeffreyDowellPhotography" target="_TOP" style="font-family: &quot;lucida grande&quot;,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #3B5998; text-decoration: none;" title="Jeffrey Dowell Photography">Jeffrey Dowell Photography</a><br/><a href="https://www.facebook.com/JeffreyDowellPhotography" target="_TOP" title="Jeffrey Dowell Photography"><img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/696174530397916.3512.386387771.png" style="border: 0px;" /></a><br/><a href="https://www.facebook.com/advertising" target="_TOP" style="font-family: &quot;lucida grande&quot;,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #3B5998; text-decoration: none;" title="Make your own badge!">Promote Your Page Too</a><!-- Facebook Badge END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<!-- Facebook Badge START -->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/JeffreyDowellPhotography" target="_TOP" title="Jeffrey Dowell Photography">
  <img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/696174530397916.3512.386387771.png" style="border: 0px;" />
</a>
<!-- Facebook Badge END -->
```

**Fiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/mvRWS/

Comment: How can I size it up the width of the RSSlink/icon?

Comment: in the `img` tag after the `border: 0px;`give it a `height:yourheightpx;width:yourwidthpx;` e.g. `height:200px;width:500px;` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mvRWS/1/